# Is it possible to access properties on dynamic composition models in Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have a few different styles/templates on my site. These templates are all used for compositions all over my site. Here's an example of my Document Types:

```
Layouts (folder)
    Style 1
    Style 2
    Style 3
Products (folder)
    ProductsPage
    Product
News (folder)
    NewsOverview
    NewsPage
```

That's basically what it looks like. All of these have templates except for `Product` and `NewsPage`, but they have `Style X` as compositions. Here is what my content nodes looks like:

```
Home
    Products
        Product 1 (Style 2)
        Product 2 (Style 3)
        Product 3 (Style 2)
        Product 4 (Style 1)
    News
        Article 1 (Style 1)
        Article 2 (Style 3)
```

and so on. You get the point? The `Style X` document types are all compositions, so I don't have to style the same page over and over again, but I can still create any style of page I want.

Now, on my parent (for example `NewsOverview`), I would like to access the properties of the children. Inside the `NewsOverview` template file, I would then have to do this:

```
@foreach(var article in Model.Content.Children) {
    dynamic image = article;
    <img src="@image.OverviewImage[0].Url" />
    <p>@article.GetPropertyValue("overviewTitle")</p>
}
```

I cannot access the properties without using strings or casting to dynamic (basically), although my models are set to Dll and I usually can do `Model.Content.PROPERTY` with intellisense and so on.

How can I achieve this? How can I access the properties without using dynamic? I understand that the children aren't necessarily all the same, but all my styled pages contains the same properties, they're just arranged differently in the template.

Comment: I'm not getting what Product 1 (Style 2) means. That  you created a product node (that with compositions has all the properties of style1-2-3) and you filled only the style 2?

Comment: @Eyescream I have a doctype called `Style 1` which has basically the same properties as the other styles. The only difference is the template. I want the user (and me) to be able to select which template to use for each page. Some pages might have more text than others, more images then others, etc. `Style 1` is simply a doctype with a template, which is a composition to the `Product` doctype.

Comment: You know you can assign multiple templates to one DocType right? Then when you create a page you just select wich one you want to use. You don't need a new DocType just to have a new template. If I understand you question properly, no, you can't use multiple templates from composed doctypes. Only the template from the parent doctype will be used. Compositions are just interfaces on Models Builder.

Answer (score 1):

There's a method called `Children<T>()` that gets all the child documents of a certain type and can thus safely be cast in a foreach:

```
@foreach(Article article in Model.Content.Children<Article>()) {
    <img src="@article.OverviewImage.First().Url" />
    <p>@article.OverviewTitle</p>
}
```

You'll probably want to add some logic around `article.OverviewImage.First()` as if there is no value for `OverviewImage` it will throw a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your parent model to the template?:

```
@inherits UmbracoViewPage<ContentModels.Product>
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to cast the children to the specific type:

```
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;

@foreach (var article in Model.Content.Children.Select(child => new ContentModels.NewsPage(child)) {
    <img src="@article .OverviewImage.First().Url" />
    <p>@article.OverviewTitle</p>
}
```

`.Children()` just gets children of type `IPublishedContent`, because the ModelsBuilder has no idea which types of documents can exist under the current page.

Comment: You can cast the children really easily. The content models are still IPublishedContent. No need to build the model again.